# Getting SQL Server values from a view on a different server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have access to a View called (vw_table) on Server1. I want to get the data
from this view (few million records) into a table on server2.

I tried

```
SELECT * INTO ##TempTable
FROM VW_Table
```

This gets the data in to ##TempTable.

Now how can I move it to a different server (server2) and to a different database?

I want Table2 in Server2 to have the data from VW_table.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Then you can't use temp tables to do this. Do a proper export of the table with SSIS or `SELECT * INTO Table2 FROM Server1.DataBase1.dbo.VW_Table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like **Lemak** said, you can't pass temporary tables around like this.  You either need to have a [Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and copy the data directly into the table, or you need to export the data and import it into the table using SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

you cant direct access another server like this.
You have to options to solve your problem:

- Configure a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) on server1 to access server2 then you do: `select * from mylinkedserver..table`
- Create a [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) package to read data from server1 and insert on server2